# open multiple files in a loop and sum them based on index (python)

Tags: python, file-io, nested-lists

I am new to python, and even more new to SO, so i hope i can get this question right.

I have a list of lists (3D) in which all elements are paths to a certain text file containing data. Like so (this is just an example):

```
lists = [[['/home/text01.txt', '/home/text02.txt', '/home/text03.txt'],
  ['/home/text04.txt', '/home/text05.txt', '/home/text06.txt'], 
  ['/home/text07.txt', '/home/text08.txt', '/home/text09.txt']],
 [['/home/text10.txt', '/home/text11.txt', '/home/text12.txt'],
  ['/home/text13.txt', '/home/text14.txt', '/home/text15.txt'],
  ['/home/text16.txt', '/home/text17.txt', '/home/text18.txt']],
 [['/home/text19.txt', '/home/text20.txt', '/home/text21.txt'],
  ['/home/text22.txt', '/home/text23.txt', '/home/text24.txt'],
  ['/home/text25.txt', '/home/text26.txt', '/home/text27.txt']]]
```

I need to sum the the values from these files, based on their index, so i would get:

```
result1 = text01 + text10 + text19
result2 = text02 + text11 + text20
result3 = ...
```

So each element of a sublist is summed with the corresponding ones in all sublists.
So far i am able to get the right results if i write one *if* loop for each *j*:

```
n=0
for i, j, k in (itertools.product(range(len(lists[0])), range(len(lists[0])), range(len(lists[0][0])))):
    if i == 0 and j == 0:
        f1 = np.loadtxt(lists[i][j][k], comments='#', skiprows=1, usecols=(2,3,5,6))
        f2 = np.loadtxt(lists[i+1][j][k], comments='#', skiprows=1, usecols=(2,3,5,6))
        f3 = np.loadtxt(lists[i+2][j][k], comments='#', skiprows=1, usecols=(2,3,5,6))
        f = f1 + f2 + f3
        np.savetxt(path0 + 'result%i' %n, f, fmt='%f %f %f %f %f')
        n = n + 1
```

then would follow

```
if i == 0 and j == 1:
...
if i == 0 and j == 2:
...
```

which works fine if i would have only a few files.

But i would like to generalize this for a large number of files, and i don't know how to open and sum files in one loop based on indices so i get the right result.
I feel like even this version of the code is crude and non-pythonic, but it worked, and that's all i got.

Any suggestions on improvements and on how to proceed from here are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid using for cycles, since you need to read the `.txt` file each time, other than that, sometihing like this should work as expected

```
n=0
# Thinking of you lists as a 3d matrix, start by cycling on the rows
for j in range(len(lists[0])):
    # then on the columns
    for i in range(len(lists[0][0])):
        # initialize f here
        f = 0
        # finally on the depth
        for k in range(len(lists)):
            # update f.
            f += np.loadtxt(lists[k][j][i], comments='#', skiprows=1, usecols=(2,3,5,6))
        #save f
        np.savetxt(path0 + 'result%i' %n, f, fmt='%f %f %f %f %f')
        # update n
        n += 1
```

As a side not, you could concatenate your lists and save a for cycle

Comment: Why did you switch OP's use of `i` and `k`?

Comment: Because you need to slice in reverse order, starting from the highest level, getting to the lowest. That slicing should return the result OP requested. You can verify it by substituting the `np.loadtxt(...)` with `lists[k][j][i]`, initializing `f=""` and removing the save part

Comment: I understand why you switched the loop nesting order; this is essentially identical to what I was about to post.  I'm asking why you switched which variable served which dimension.  It's a minor issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought it made the code more readable, I can edit it if it actually makes it less readable

Comment: Thank you, it works well like this, and the renaming of variables was not a problem, i understand what happened.